# Example of continuous function $f:(\mathbb R $ \ $ \mathbb Q) \cap [0,1] \to \mathbb Q \cap [0,1] $

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

i) How do we find an example of a surjective continuous function ( if exists)

$f:(\mathbb R $ \ $ \mathbb Q) \cap [0,1] \to \mathbb Q \cap [0,1] $ ?

ii) How do we find an example of a continuous function ( if exists)

$f:(\mathbb R $ \ $ \mathbb Q) \cap [0,1] \to \mathbb Q \cap [0,1] $ ?

Comment: For (ii), you can take a constant function.

Comment: For i), you can look at the strange irrationality condition by saying that you want a function $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$ such that its restriction to $\mathbb R\backslash \mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$ is still surjective (this makes easier the interpretation of a continuous function).

Comment: @jflipp: thanks for (ii)

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: But you can't assume that your $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$. All we know is that it is continuous on $(\mathbb R$ \ $\mathbb Q) \cap [0,1]$.

Comment: @TonyK : Bleh, thought I had it. Never mind

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: Please explain ....

Answer (score 7):

For (ii) take a constant function, as already suggested in the comments. Every constant function is continuous (from any domain).

For (i), split $(\Bbb R \setminus\mathbb Q) \cap [0,1]$ into countably many (relatively) open, disjoint intervals, each with rational endpoints. This could be done in many ways, but perhaps the easiest it to let $I_n=(\frac1{n+1},\frac1n)\setminus\mathbb Q$ for each $n\ge1$, then $(\Bbb R \setminus\mathbb Q) \cap [0,1]=\cup_{n\ge1}I_n$. Also, the rationals are countable, so list them as $\mathbb Q \cap [0,1]=\{q_n:n\ge1\}$. Define $f$ so that it sends all points of $I_n$ onto singleton $\{q_n\}$. Then $f$ is continuous since the preimage of every set (open or not) is the union of (relatively) open intervals, and hence is (relatively) open, that is, open in the topology of $(\Bbb R \setminus\mathbb Q) \cap [0,1]$.

Comment: very nice solution! locally constant function on a totally disconnected space